# Aligning text on a box

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have this flip box which looks like this

[image: FlipBox]

When I hover on it, it would turn around and would look like this.

[image]

I want to know, how do I move the text to the right only, I tried putting text-align: right; on my css but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```css
.box9 {
  background-color: #4C586F;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 45px;
}

.box10 {
  background-image: url("../img/commended/erwin.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_third">
  <div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="box9">
        <p style="font-size:180%; color: white">Kudos!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="box10">
        <p style="font-size:180%; color: black">sdasdsadas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *That image though.*

Comment: @the4kman omg...

Comment: Where are you trying to declare the `text-align` rule? It should work if you declare it on `.box10 p`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I did put it on box10 and it would still be in the middle

Comment: @JoeF `.box10` or `.box10 p`? You'll want to declare this rule on the `p` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this, setting `text-align: right` in the back view and to `center` in the front view, vertical centering of the `p` tag and also changing some other settings (no padding [therefore changed width and height settings]  and some other details):

```css
.box9 {
  background-color: #4C586F;
  width: 340px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box10 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150x250/);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 340px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
}

.box9 p,
.box10 p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box10 p {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_third">
  <div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="box9">
        <p style="font-size:180%; color: white">Kudos!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="box10">
        <p style="font-size:180%; color: black">sdasdsadas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```